# What's wrong with this asynchronous code?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, active-directory

I have the code below which retrieves groups from Active Directory. When I run the code only for `MY_GROUP_NAME` (commented out below), the output is as expected.

When I run for the full set of groups from AD, the final data set is incorrect.  One specific example, is that I end up with multiple adGroups in the list with the same group name but different ParentGroupGuids. This is an invalid scenario.  This problem appears to have something to do with the `Parallel.ForEach()` calling the recursive method below.

Any idea what the issue might be and how to fix?

```
private ConcurrentBag<Core.Models.ADGroup> adGroups;        

public async Task<List<Core.Models.ADGroup>> GetADGroupsFromADAsync(string domainName)
{
    return await Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        var domainId = await new DomainRepository().GetDomainId(domainName);

        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
        {
            var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(new GroupPrincipal(context));
            Parallel.ForEach(
                ps.FindAll().ToList(),
                //ps.FindAll().Where(x => x.Name == "MY_GROUP_NAME").ToList(),
                new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
                async (group, loopState) =>
                {
                    await GetGroupsRecursive((Guid)domainId, null, (GroupPrincipal)group);
                });
        }

        //return group list
        return adGroups.ToList();
    });
}

private async Task GetGroupsRecursive(Guid domainId, Guid? parentGroupGuid, GroupPrincipal group)
{
    //cast result to adgroup
    var adGroup = Mapper.Map<Core.Models.ADGroup>(group);

    //set domainid
    adGroup.DomainId = domainId;

    //set parent group id
    adGroup.ParentGroupGuid = parentGroupGuid;

    //process child groups
    foreach (var member in group.Members)
        if (member is GroupPrincipal)
            await GetGroupsRecursive(domainId, adGroup.Guid, (GroupPrincipal)member);

    //add to the list
    adGroups.Add(adGroup);
}
```

Comment: please see my updated answer, there is a 2nd more major problem that is more likely the source of your error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not safe to use a `PrincipalContext` from multiple threads concurrently. Internally the `group.Members` call you have in `GetGroupsRecursive` [will call](https://source.dot.net/#System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Group.cs,5bc9fabc53553388) `ContextRaw.QueryCtx.GetGroupMembership(this, false);` which uses the Principal Context.

This likely causes the errors you are having. You either need a context per thread or not multi-thread the member lookups.

**EDIT:** Also another major problem your code has (did not see it till I was trying to write up a example), you are using async/await with a `Parallel.ForEach` call. ***This is not supported,*** you can only do synchronous methods with `Parallel.ForEach`, get rid of the async or switch to [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).

Here is a example of fixing the async/await and making it a context per thread

```
public async Task<List<Core.Models.ADGroup>> GetADGroupsFromADAsync(string domainName)
{
    return await Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        var domainId = await new DomainRepository().GetDomainId(domainName);

        using (var searchContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
        {
            var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(new GroupPrincipal(searchContext));
            Parallel.ForEach(
                ps.FindAll().Select(x=>x.DistinguishedName),
                new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
                () => new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName),
                (distinguishedName, loopState, threadLocalContext) =>
                {
                    var threadLocalGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(threadLocalContext, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, distinguishedName);
                    GetGroupsRecursive((Guid)domainId, null, threadLocalGroup);
                    return threadLocalContext;
                },
                threadLocalContext => threadLocalContext.Dispose());
        }

        //return group list
        return adGroups.ToList();
    });
}

private void GetGroupsRecursive(Guid domainId, Guid? parentGroupGuid, GroupPrincipal group)
{
    //cast result to adgroup
    var adGroup = Mapper.Map<Core.Models.ADGroup>(group);

    //set domainid
    adGroup.DomainId = domainId;

    //set parent group id
    adGroup.ParentGroupGuid = parentGroupGuid;

    //process child groups
    foreach (var member in group.Members)
        if (member is GroupPrincipal)
            GetGroupsRecursive(domainId, adGroup.Guid, (GroupPrincipal)member);

    //add to the list
    adGroups.Add(adGroup);
}
```